# Java replaceAll: Cannot replace string with backslash

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, substring

In my Java program, I am trying to replace a substring that contains a backslash within a string (`paloalto\` to `sanjose\`). However, even when I use a double backslash in order to mitigate the effect of the backslash as an escape character, I still get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 9
paloalto\
         ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Below is my Code:

```
String original = "paloalto\\adam paloalto\\jack paloalto\\justin";
System.out.println("original = " + original);

String sanjose = original.replaceAll("paloalto\\", "sanjose\\");
System.out.println("backgammon  = " + sanjose);
```

Comment: You need four backslashes: two for the regex and two for the compiler. But why are you doing this?

Comment: @EJP Eight backslashes. Four in the regex, four in the replacement. Java the docs say that backslashes in the replacement can be used to escape characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` will work for you, `replaceAll` uses regex and `\\` is a prefix for special characters, like `\\s` is white-space, `\\.` is any character, etc.

```
String test = "paloalto\\paloalto\\";
test = test.replace("paloalto\\", "sanhose\\");
System.out.println(test);
```

For `replaceAll` you can use the result of `Pattern.quote` as the first argument and the result of `Matcher.quoteReplacement` as the second:

```
test = test.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("paloalto\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("sanjose\\"));
```

[Documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 4):

You need four backslashes: Two backslashes for declaring the String in Java (that will be one backslash in the actual string), and you need two backslashes in the regular expression as a backslash again is a special character for the regex engine:

```
original.replaceAll("paloalto\\\\", "sanjose\\\\");
```

You can make use of [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) if you find this easier to read:

```
original.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("paloalto\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("sanjose\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give regex to replaceAll function and \(backspace) is escape char in java. That's why you need to repeat it 4 times to catch in string.

```
    String original = "paloalto\\adam paloalto\\jack paloalto\\justin";
    System.out.println("original = " + original);

    String sanjose = original.replaceAll("paloalto\\\\", "sanjose\\\\");
    System.out.println("backgammon  = " + sanjose);
```

This snipped will do what you want. Its output is

```
original = paloalto\adam paloalto\jack paloalto\justin
backgammon  = sanjose\adam sanjose\jack sanjose\justin
```